# Error using Thread.sleep in an Asynctask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask, sleep

I am trying to add some sleep-time in my Asynctask because right now my ProgressDialog is too fast when there isn't much data to load.

I tried this:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading first thing...");
        firstThing();
        progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        //...repeat above four lines a few times for second, third, fourth thing, etc
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyClassName", "There was an error: " + e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am getting the error "Only the original thread that created a view can touch its views."

Comment: You are updating UI Views outside Android main thread. DoInBackground run in other thread, so you cant update views. So, if you want to update the view you should use, onPreExectute, onPostExecture or onProgressUpdate. Check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I have those overridden as well, yes, I just didn't post those here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to override `onProgressUpdate()` as well as `doInBackground()`.

```
            // do this before asynctask.execute();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading first thing...");


@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        firstThing();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        // this method invokes onProgressUpdate on the UI thread
        publishProgress();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyClassName", "There was an error: " + e);
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
    progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
}
```

Comment: you can also consider showing downloaded size as percentage like that. publishProgress(percentage); and pDialog.incrementProgressBy(params[0]);

Comment: What is publishProgress() supposed to look like?

Comment: Nevermind apparently it's a built-in function. Anyways after making that edit, I still get the same error. Or maybe it's because I am setting the message in the background thread. How do I change the message depending on where in the loading process I am?

Comment: What does `firstThing()` do? Does it update the UI?  You can't update the UI in `doInBackground()`, because it's a non-UI thread.  That's what keeps the UI responsive, because the UI thread can still run while your background task is doing stuff.